# Distinguish positive recurrent, null recurrent and transient

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given transition probability as below, how can I tell that the Markov Chain $X_n$ is a positive recurrent, null recurrent or transient?

$$p(x,0)=1/(x^2+1),\quad  p(x,x+1)=(x^2+1)/(x^2+2)$$ state space $S=\{0,1,2,...\}$

I have tried to calculate $\alpha(x)$ for $x \in S$, but it turns out to be $1$ for all $x$. So it is recurrent. Then try to find invariant probability distribution, but meet some trouble here.

Comment: Hint: Can you compute $P_0(T_0\ \text{finite})$?

Comment: More details about it?

Comment: Sure, you first.

Comment: I have tried to calculate alpha(x) for x in S, but it turns out to be 1 for all x. so it is recurrent. Then try to find invariant probability distribution, but meet some trouble here.

Comment: Please recheck the transition probabilities: why don't they add up to 1?